# How to print a Hidden DIV when printing using a JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, function, printing

I have a javascript print function:

```
    function printDetails() {
        var printContent = document.getElementById('<%= divMail.ClientID %>');

        var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
        var uniqueName = new Date();
        var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();
        var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=500,top=500,width=0,height=0');
        printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);

        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.focus();
        printWindow.print();

        printWindow.close();

        return false;
    }
```

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="divMail" runat="server" >
    <div id="showTopDetailsContent" style="display: none; position:relative;">
        MORE HTML
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following JQuery/Script:

```
$('#showTopDetailsContent').toggle(300);
```

The problem:
When I Print I get the Contents of the divMail (DIV) and send them to the Print Function, the problem is that since I have a DIV inside divMail that is Hidden it will not be displayed in the Print. How do I make the Print Function Display that hidden DIV?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
printWindow.document.getElementById('showTopDetailsContent').style.display='block';
```

after the

```
printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify it as visible for printing in CSS:

```
@media screen {
    #showTopDetailsContent { display: none; }
    #showTopDetailsContent.show { display: block; }
}
@media print {
    #showTopDetailsContent { display: block !important; }
}
```

And instead of using `.toggle()` which applies inline styles, use a class.

```
$('#showTopDetailsContent').toggleClass('show');
```

Comment: I don't know someone else thumbed down your comment, anyway, it did not work because the print function opens a new window and the @media print is not available there.

Comment: @EricBergman - If the CSS block is inside the DIV `divMail` it will be available in the printWindow as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to suppress the border in CSS

```
/* stop page from printing footer */
@page {
    size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
}
```

but that will put your content close to the edge so I'd wrap everything in a DIV with some padding